# clock() returning a negative value in C

Tags: c, clock, time.h, time-t

I'm using a quite simple code to measure for time of execution.It works well until I am not sure may be not more than 20 minutes.But after(>20min.)it is returning negative results.I searched throughout the forums and tried everything like changing the datatype,using long unsigned (which is returning 0) but failed again.
The following is the snippet of my code

```
main()
{
    time_t start,stop;
    double time_arm;
    start = clock(); 
    /* .......  */
    stop = clock();
    time_arm=(double)(stop-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Time Taken by ARM only is %lf \n",time_arm);
}
```

output is 
Time Taken by ARM only is **-2055.367296**

Any help is appreciated,thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: `clock()` returns type `clock_t`.

Comment: Don't use `clock()`. It's buggy on nearly every real-world implementation, and would not do anything useful even if it weren't buggy.

Answer (score 6):

POSIX requires `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to be 1,000,000.  That means your count is in microseconds - and 2<sup>31</sup> microseconds is about 35 minutes.  Your timer is just overflowing, so you can't get meaningful results when that happens.

Why you see the problem at 20 minutes, I'm not sure - maybe your `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` isn't POSIX-compatible.  Regardless, your problem is timer overflow.  You'll need to handle this problem in a different way - maybe look into [`getrusage(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage).

Comment: Note that this is a bug in the implementation. C requires `clock` to fail (returning `(clock_t)-1`) if the result is not representable; wrapping is not permitted. See the interpretation for [Austin Group issue 686](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=686).

Answer (score 2):

`clock_t` is long which is a 32-bit signed value - it can hold 2^31 before it overflows. On a 32-bit system the `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` value is equal to `1000000` [as mentioned by POSIX] clock() will return the same value almost after every 72 minutes.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30.aspx) also it can return -1.

> The elapsed wall-clock time since the start of the process (elapsed
>   time in seconds times CLOCKS_PER_SEC). **If the amount of elapsed time
>   is unavailable, the function returns –1**, cast as a clock_t.

**On a side note:-**

`clock()` measures CPU time used by the program and it does NOT measure real time and `clock()` return value is specified in microseconds.

Comment: Was looking into the definition of `clock_t`.  Found nothing to say it is `long`, only its "range and precision ... are implementation-defined".  (C11dr 7.21.1)  Do you have some useful reference to show it is 'long' or 32-bit?

Comment: @chux:- I am not going to bet that it is long but I have found that long is usually used. As for one refernce you can check this:- **In the GNU system, clock_t is equivalent to long int and CLOCKS_PER_SEC is an integer value.** http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_19.html Do correct me if I am wrong? :(

Comment: @chux:- Is that wrong? Or did I missed something. Please do comment if I missed anything. Thanks! :)

Comment: Copied that reference: In GNU clock_t is a `long int`  Now I wonder if in a GNU system, is a `long int` 32-bit or at least 32-bit.  Hmmm.  I suspect the latter.

Comment: @chux:- It is 32 bit what I have learnt so far. Do correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: [Integer Types](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Integer-Types) say 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: @chux:- Yes thats correct. Got it. Thanks for updating my knowledge. +1 P.S. Do I need to do some corrections in my answer also?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39215/discussion-between-chux-and-rahul-tripathi)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `clock_gettime()` with the `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` option if you are on a POSIX system. `clock_gettime()` uses `struct timespec` to return time information so doesn't suffer from the same problem as using a single integer.