# clock() returning negative time difference on Windows machine

Tags: c, windows

I wrote following program in C to calculate the execution time **(On a Windows-7 machine)**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
double time_spent = 0.0;
clock_t begin;
clock_t end;

begin = clock();
    // code to read a file 
end = clock();
time_spent += ((double)(end - begin)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

printf("Time elapsed is %f seconds", time_spent);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

At the end of the execution, the value of the `(end-begin)` is negative.
Also, the value of `begin` was 46 while that of `end` was 43 after the program execution.

I am using a 64-bit Windows-7.

1. Can someone please explain why the value of `end` is smaller than `begin`.
2. How can this be fixed on a **windows machine**.

([clock() returning a negative value in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366943/clock-returning-a-negative-value-in-c)
talks about POSIX only).

Comment: @Blindy This solution talks about POSIX, will it not be different on windows machine?
Correct me if I am wrong but clock() behaves differently on windows and on UNIX.

Comment: If you're looking for a Windows only solution, you have `QueryPerformanceCounter`. You mentioned [c], but if you have access to C++ as well, the portable equivalent is the standard `chrono` library, which uses QPC internally in Windows..

Comment: I  _voted to close_ before seeing the ***emphasis on Windows 7*** (edited in during my vote.) .   The linked duplicate is specific to Linux and does not address this question.  Am voting to reopen.

Comment: `clock()` wraps around (like a real clock) so a time in the past can have a greater value than now (same as 4 hours before 2am is 10pm: `2 - 10 = -8` / `2 - 22 = -20`)

Comment: @pmg Assuming the OP uses (a compiler that uses) Windows' UCRT, `clock()` does not wrap around but rather [returns `-1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/clock?view=vs-2019) once it hits `LONG_MAX` after 25 days or so.

Comment: @Blindy The UCRT `clock()` on Windows uses QPC as well.

Comment: the statement: `#include <time.h>`  exposes the function: `difftime()`.   the syntax is; `double difftime(time_t time1, time_t time0);`  Using that function, you will not be getting negative elapsed time in your code, as the elapsed number of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

In windows 7 there are a whole series of clocks and interval timers available, both physical and via interfaces. Exactly which cpu(s)??? Certain time/timer functions WILL appear to run backwards!!! At least for short intervals/resolutions. This is a well known issue. See the Mircosoft web stuff. You probably want the win32 API interval timers, at a guess.